# set access_token in httpheader in axios using typescript and webpack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, razor, single-page-application, axios

I want to set access_token in header of axios as shown in following.

https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults

Now I am getting access_token using razor syntax which is only available in CSHTML file.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Clients/src/MvcHybrid/Views/Home/Secure.cshtml

I am using typescript with vue.js using [JavascriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)

How can I set(pass) this **await Context.GetTokenAsync("access_token")** in my typescript file (lets say boot.ts) to set to axios default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed following as an alternative. So no need of above use case.

https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2347